# Getting "Response status code does not indicate success: 502 (Bad Gateway)" from Asp.net Core MVC Web App hosted in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

I have a client application built on Asp.net core MVC (V 1.1.1) and a Web API built on Asp.net core (v 2.1). I had hosted both on Azure.

While making some requests, the web app is failing and giving 502 Bad Gateway response.

> Response status code does not indicate success: 502 (Bad Gateway).
>
> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

This issue is intermittent, however, seems happening when request is taking more than 2 min to process. I have set up requestTimeout to 20 min on both client and API side in Web.config file still didn't get it resolved. Sometimes, the same request is being processed in less time and I am getting response.

Additionally, the 5 min timeout for Httpclient has also been set but no luck.

`<aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00"/>`

`_httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);`

I have tested the app locally and can't face this issue, also able to get response even it take more than 3 min to process.

It seems that Azure web app is not waiting for request to get processed if it's crossing 2 min. However, the azure session timeout specifies 230 seconds (3.8 min) but still it's not waiting and the app is not considering this case as an error and not logging anything.

**Client Side code:**

```
public class ApiClientFactory
{
    private static Uri ApiUrl;
    private static Lazy<ApiClient> restClient = new Lazy<ApiClient>(
        () => new ApiClient(ApiUrl),
        LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    static ApiClientFactory()
    {
        ApiUrl = new Uri(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebAPIUrl"]));
    }

    public static ApiClient Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return restClient.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ApiClient
{
   private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
   private readonly Uri BaseEndPointUrl;

   public ApiClient(Uri baseEndPointUrl)
   {
       if (baseEndPointUrl == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("baseEndPointUrl");

       BaseEndPointUrl = baseEndPointUrl;
       _httpClient = new HttpClient();
       _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
       _httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0); //Timeout needed for few modules to get results from db.
   }

   private HttpContent CreateHttpContent<T>(T content)
   {
       var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content, MicrosoftDateFormatSettings);
       return new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   }

   private static JsonSerializerSettings MicrosoftDateFormatSettings
   {
       get
       {
           return new JsonSerializerSettings
           {
               DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
           };
       }
   }

   public async Task<T1> PostAsync<T1, T2>(string url, T2 content, string token)
   {
       try
       {
           _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
           var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, CreateHttpContent<T2>(content));

           if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError){
               var exception = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               throw new Exception(exception);
           }
           response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
           var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

           return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T1>(data);
       }
       catch (Exception ex){throw ex;}
   }
}
```

Please assist where it's having an issue.

Comment: It sounds like you might have some sort of Deadlock in your code?  Is it possible that this could be happening on the server?  Generally a 502 means that the server you received the 502 from timed out while trying to communicate with another server.

Comment: I am not aware of Deadlocks but the mentioned issue is not happening while I run the 2 apps locally. Do you mean the communication between hosted client & API has problem???

Comment: Yes. If I have understood you correctly, you have ``WebBrowser<--->MVC<--->WebAPI``.  A 502 implies to me that the "MVC client" is timing out when talking to the "Web API" this would most likely be a networking problem or be because the WebAPI is getting into a Deadlock.

Comment: I think you are right, seems it's happening only in the hosted client app, Now also I tested in local and able to receive response even after 4.7 min waiting time but this waiting is timing out in server I guess. Do you think we need to tweak anything in Azure settings for this time out.??

Also, I am sure it's not happening in API as I have a custom error handler in it and there I am explicitly setting HttpStatusCode to 500 and sending error information to client. As we are getting 502, it should be from client app.

Comment: I don't know sorry, I think you will need to direct this to an Azure forum.  I suggest deleting this question when you're done, I don't think it's relevant to SO.

Comment: Are you hosting your web app in IIS?

Comment: Hosted both apps  in Azure. While running locally, no issues at all.

Comment: I hope there is no cors related issue .. just a hunch.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a method that retry your requests, or simply use .Net [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) for this kind of errors. Is not a good practice to increase your timeout setup.

**Method**:

```
    private async Task<bool> PostAsync()//Params you need
    {
        HttpStatusCode[] httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying =
        {
            HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout,
            HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            HttpStatusCode.BadGateway,
            HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable,
            HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout
        };

        var maxAttempts = 0;

        while (maxAttempts < 3)
        {
            var response =  await _httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, CreateHttpContent<T2>(content));
            if (!httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying.Contains(response.StatusCode))
            {
                return true;
            }

            maxAttempts ++;
            await Task.Delay(300);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Polly**:

```
    private async Task PostAsync()//Params you need
    {
        HttpStatusCode[] httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying =
        {
            HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout,
            HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            HttpStatusCode.BadGateway,
            HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable,
            HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout
        };


        _retryPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
            .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying.Contains(r.StatusCode))
            .WaitAndRetry(4, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));

        _retryPolicy.Execute(await _httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, CreateHttpContent<T2>(content)));

    }
```

Comment: I found the following helpful:
These packages:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry/

to use this Retry Logic that adds this recommended jitter: Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2

Answer (score 0):

We thought that the following could be the possible reasons.

1. At the time of testing, Network related issue between two hosted applications while processing the given 
   request and to deliver the response. Before the API delivers the response the Web app 
   might be timing out.
2. Made the following code change in the API client class. (it's posted in the question).I am not certain about the subtle difference between **awaiting** the task and getting the **Result** from the task. But after this change we no longer experienced the issue, additionally did some load testing also but still didn't face that later on.

From

```
var response =  await _httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, CreateHttpContent<T2>(content));
```

To

```
var response =  _httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, CreateHttpContent<T2>(content)).Result;
```

**Note:** Enabling the Analytics options for the hosted domains in Azure would give us good insights to narrow down this type of issues.